# Restricting which MIME types a template will render in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionview

Given:

- A `FooController` with a `bar` action
- An ActionView template handler for the `custom` extension
- A template at `app/views/foo/bar.custom`

Is there a way to make Rails render that template only for HTML requests without renaming the template to `bar.html.custom`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do this using a custom `ActionView::Responder`. See https://github.com/netzpirat/haml_coffee_assets/issues/80 for details of why this was needed and how I solved it.